# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' for .find

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to webscraping and trying to get information from Google Trends website about the Average of keywords used.

Currently I am getting the error $AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. I think that the error is because 'bar-chart-content' as a class may not exist as the name in HTML.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=pikachu,Cat'

page = requests.get(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'bar-chart-content'}).find_all('td') #Gives the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Please tell me to how to fix this issue and any suggestions on how to find the correct class name in the future for a website excluding inspect [if that is the issue] ?

**EDIT:** Based on MePsyDuck's answer, the class does not exist so how can find the correct name?

Comment: The issue here is you are reading the source code and parsing it but the content like the bargraph is not static, so one the html is returned there are then events that trigger and modify the html and add in content. Requests wont see those updates as it doesnt execute the code or events. so you wont see the bar-chart-content class as its added into the html after the page loads

Comment: An easier way to think of this is that requests wont execute javascript events. turn off java script in your browser and refresh the URL and you should see you dont get any graphs. This is exactly how requests sees the html

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle urllib2 library will help with this or is there any other way around it?

Comment: you would need to use something like selenium. thats what i have used in the past to deal with sites that load content via javascript or ajax

Comment: you can trying using chrome extension selectorgadget, which will help you to find correct css [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en)

Comment: The issue here isnt that the class doesnt exist. When you load the page in a browser and the java script events trigger the class does exist. The issue here is the OP is getting the source html via requests which doesnt deal with javascript events as such the class tag is never loaded into the html when called using requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if soup finds any `<div>` before trying to find `td`.
If there is no `<div>` with your specified class, then the `div` object will be None (which we can check easily).

Replace the last line in your code with:

```py
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'bar-chart-content'})
if div is not None:
    table = div..find_all('td') 
    # Process futher
```

Comment: how do you find the correct name though as I have used inspect to take out the div class name?

Comment: Try to find a pattern, something that can uniquely identify whatever you are looking for. For your use case, I would rather recommend you to use [pytrends](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/) python package to get the trends data.

Comment: Better yet, you can also directly send a request to this [url](https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline?hl=en-US&tz=-330&req={"time":"2018-07-04+2019-07-04","resolution":"WEEK","locale":"en-US","comparisonItem":[{"geo":{"country":"US"},"complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"BROAD","value":"pikachu"}]}},{"geo":{"country":"US"},"complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"BROAD","value":"Cat"}]}}],"requestOptions":{"property":"","backend":"IZG","category":0}}&token=foobar&tz=-330) and get the values in the form of JSON object.

Comment: Only thing you need to change in url is the keywords, locale, time, resolution and token.

Comment: can you give me an example for the URL?

Comment: I already replied with a sample url in my second comment. To get it working you'll need your token, which you can get by monitoring network tab in your browser's developer tools. Try to look for request that has this url `/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline`. The request should have your token.